# How to display a matrix of correlations with missing entries?

Tags: r, data-visualization, correlation

I'd like to obtain a graphic representation of the correlations in articles I have gathered so far to easily explore the relationships between variables. I used to draw a (messy) graph but I have too much data now.

Basically, I have a table with:

- [0]: name of variable 1
- [1]: name of variable 2
- [2]: correlation value

The "overall" matrix is incomplete (e.g., I have the correlation of V1*V2, V2*V3, but not V1*V3).

Is there a way to graphically represent this ?

Answer (score 12):

Building upon @GaBorgulya's response, I would suggest trying fluctuation or level plot (aka heatmap displays).

For example, using [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/):

```
library(ggplot2, quietly=TRUE)
k <- 100
rvals <- sample(seq(-1,1,by=.001), k, replace=TRUE)
rvals[sample(1:k, 10)] <- NA
cc <- matrix(rvals, nr=10)
ggfluctuation(as.table(cc)) + opts(legend.position="none") + 
  labs(x="", y="")
```

(Here, missing entry are displayed in plain gray, but the default color scheme can be changed, and you can also put "NA" in the legend.)

[image]

or

```
ggfluctuation(as.table(cc), type="color") + labs(x="", y="") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red",  high = "blue")
```

(Here, missing values are simply not displayed. However, you can add a `geom_text()` and display something like "NA" in the empty cell.)

[image]

Comment: +1 for `ggfluctuation`, hadn't seen that before! This post has other useful code to visualize this type of dater: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453336/r-plot-correlation-matrix-into-a-graph/5453398#5453398

Comment: @Chase (+1) Thx. BTW, it seems I had some problem with my color scheme for negative correlation values.

Comment: Reordering the rows and columns by (`hclust(…)$order`)[http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/hclust.html] the visualization will be often easier to overview.

Comment: @GaBorgulya Good point. I use this when I'm doing exploratory data analysis *and* the variables have no particular order (as would be the case for spatial or temporal data, or structured data that you want to see as is). The `mixOmics::cim` function is very good for that. A related issue was discussed here, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8370/how-to-visualize-summarize-a-matrix-with-number-of-rows-gg-number-of-columns/8372#8372.

Answer (score 5):

Your data may be like

```
  name1 name2 correlation
1    V1    V2         0.2
2    V2    V3         0.4
```

You can rearrange your long table into a wide one with the following R code

```
d = structure(list(name1 = c("V1", "V2"), name2 = c("V2", "V3"), 
    correlation = c(0.2, 0.4)), .Names = c("name1", "name2", 
    "correlation"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
k = d[, c(2, 1, 3)]
names(k) = names(d)
e = rbind(d, k)
x = with(e, reshape(e[order(name2),], v.names="correlation", 
  idvar="name1", timevar="name2", direction="wide"))
x[order(x$name1),]
```

You get

```
  name1 correlation.V1 correlation.V2 correlation.V3
1    V1             NA            0.2             NA
3    V2            0.2             NA            0.4
4    V3             NA            0.4             NA
```

Now you can use techniques for visualizing correlation matrices (at least ones that can cope with missing values).

Comment: the `reshape` package can be useful as well. Once you have `e`, consider something like `library(reshape) cast(melt(e), name1 ~ name2)`

Answer (score 3):

The `corrplot` package is a useful function for visualizing correlation matrices. It accepts a correlation matrix as the input object and has several options for displaying the matrix itself. A nice feature is that it can reorder your variables using hierarchical clustering or PCA methods.

See the accepted answer in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2086/quickly-evaluate-visually-correlations-between-ordered-categorical-data-in-r) for an example visualization.